# Tripadvisor widget is doing mess in my code and I cannot edit it

Tags: html, css, widget

In the footer of the website, I would like to include social widgets. Facebook one is working just fine, Tripadvisor comes with a many lines of code and and is not really styled, jumps off my footer etc.

How do I eventually style the widget which is not styled? If I change anything in the code, a message:

> "Please check the TripAdvisor code and install again."

This is their code

```
<div id="TA_socialButtonBubbles675" class="TA_socialButtonBubbles">
    <ul id="7xYqVoY8wKU" class="TA_links LV2VKytU2yB">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g274707-d6883393-  Reviews-I_Love_Segway_Private_Tours-Prague_Bohemia.html">
            <img src="http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/socialWidget/20x28_green-21693-2.png"/>
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=socialButtonBubbles&amp;uniq=675&amp;locationId=6883393&amp;color=green&amp;size=rect&amp;lang=en_US&amp;langversion=2"></script>
```

The main problem is that it jumps out of the footer and does not stay in line like I would like to.

Screenshot: 
[image]

The whole site to check is : http://ilovesegway.com

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you to get it exactly like you want is for you to open your site in your browser of choice and tinker with the styling in the browsers developer tools.

I went in and slightly modified the parent div. I gave it a `display: inline-block`

`<div id="TA_socialButtonBubbles675"
    class="TA_socialButtonBubbles"
    style="display: inline-block">...`

That wasn't enough so I also changed two children divs to inherit the `vertical-align` styles.

`<div class="socialWidgetContainer"` had a style of `display: table-cell` which I removed.

`<div class="socialWidget" style="vertical-align: inherit;"`

I assume the second modification was generated content by trip advisor, but you should still be able to style this via a `.css` file or even some `JavaScript`.

I did all this through the chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an iframe, similar to what the Facebook widget uses? That way, you could put the TripAdvisor code in a separate HTML fragment and let the iframe dictate where you want the widget to go. That way, you're not fighting against whatever styles are being pushed at you from TripAdvisor's scripts.

```
<!-- Facebook widget -->
<a href="#"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FI-Love-Segway%2F540468152732697&amp;width=100&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=487866241269315" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:35px;padding-top:15px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></a>

<!-- Trip Advisor widget; add whatever styles or parameters you need -->
<a href="#"><iframe src="YOURSITE/tripaddvisor.php"></iframe></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still apply css rules to the included content. Consider making #TA_socialButtonBubbles675 position:relative and moving it manually to where you would like it to appear. I had some luck with:

```
#TA_socialButtonBubbles675
{
position: relative;
top: -116px;
left: 360px;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a robust way of styling IMO. I do agree this should be done via styling or in the worst case scripting that modifies style, but there are better ways to implement it.